# I'm trying to do wordbuilding for my sci-fi world, and I need tech level entries

Tags: technological-development, worldbuilding-process

I was thinking of having 15 tech levels, with 3 pieces of example technology or inventions per level. Can someone use an imagination better than mine to make this for me?

Level 1: Stone Age

Level 2: Bronze Age

Level 3: Iron Age

Level 4: Medieval

Level 5: Renaissance

Level 6: Industrial Revolution

Level 7: Atomic Age

Level 8: Space Age

Level 9: Information Age

Level 10: Post-Information Age

Level 11: Nanotech Age

Level 12: Antimatter Age

Level 13: Far Future Age

Level 14: Interstellar Age

Level 15: Age of Transcendence

Comment: This is a very open-ended question.  Can you narrow it down to one specific area where you're stuck?  Can you break it into smaller questions that have more concrete answers?  (You might have some luck on history.SE asking about seminal techs of the Bronze Age, for example.)

Comment: I'm stuck just on thinking of unique and creative technologies. I don't want basic stuff. I was really looking for a variety of different things. I will even settle if someone can direct me to a link to someone's homebrew tech levels

Comment: You'll find that Stack Exchange sites are best at handling questions with clear answers.  They're really not good at open-ended discussions.

Comment: Try breaking your question up: ask about good tech levels, then (separately) ask about techs for a particular level you're having trouble with.

Comment: I just would like at least 3 tech ideas for each level. They should be milestones.

Comment: Have you considered using the tech trees from one of the video games as inspiration?  Civilization or Age of Empires are natural subjects with a wealth of ideas behind them.

Comment: Unless you have a specific criteria of what is a milestone technology, it is going to be subjective and everyone will come up with different ideas. If your looking for ideas : http://wiki.travellerrpg.com/Technology_level http://wiki.travellerrpg.com/Tech_Level_Comparison_Chart http://gurps.wikia.com/wiki/Tech_Level

Comment: Gentlemen, we have now entered the Far Future age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are science fiction roleplaying games which provide such things. Depending on what you want to do with your fictional world, you might go there for inspiration.

- Traveller has had half a dozen editions since the *little black books* of the 70s.
- GURPS has had four editions.

Like your list of tech levels, they incorporate assumptions about the development of future technology. Your list makes nanotech "earlier" than the interstellar age. That means by the time you have explorers who boldly explore planets where no man has gone before, they have nanotech, antimatter, etc. Do you really want interstellar explorers to have all those tools? Where is the adventure in that?

Start with the age where your stories happen. Select a technology mix that makes those stories possible. For instance, do you want human protagonists or robots with AI? Do you want easy interstellar travel? FTL or STL?

Then consider some things which might be "on the horizon" in your stories. Perhaps research on those technologies is a McGuffin for an espionage story. Consider what you don't want them to have. The transporters and replicators from Star Trek have the potential to shortcut many plots if you think it through, so perhaps they're not suitable.

Comment: +1.  My first thought on reading this question was GURPS; the tech levels it breaks out are very similar to those listed above (putting us currently in TL8).  I don't recall if the tech levels are listed in the free GURPS Lite intro or not - and my books aren't available at the moment - but I'd definitely second this one.  [link](http://www.sjgames.com/gurps/lite/)